# Accelerometer Data over Specific time (javascript)

Tags: javascript, accelerometer

Is there anyway I can retreive accelerometer data over a specific time frame using the `window.ondevicemotion`

That is. I want the user to click a button then shake the phone for a fixed period of time (say five seconds) and retrieve the average speed at which he/she is shaking on all three axis.

Is there a way i can do this?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Bind the event handler when the button was clicked and remove it after a fixed period of time.

Comment: would that get the average acceleration over that peroid of time?

Comment: No, that would only let you get the data over the specific time, which I thought is what you wanted to know. You'd then have to process the data and compute whatever value you want.

Comment: so would i need to save all the generated data in a global variable?

Comment: It doesn't have to be global, but yes, you'd have to store the data somehow.

Comment: how would you do it without a global variable? it doesn't seem to work with global variables anyway, because i think the listener creates  anew thread.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. Why do you think you need a global variable? You just need some variable to store the data in. Whether it is global or not doesn't matter. If you want it to be global, go ahead.

Comment: I'm still not sure how that would work. The binded event will run over and over?

Comment: Well yes, as long as the handler is bound, you will receive data. Then after 5sec you unbind the event handler and process the data.

Comment: Yes. I've done that. It doesn't work though

Comment: Maybe if you post your code, explain what outcome you get and what outcome you expect, we can help you better.